# How to display an ImageView on the whole screen on android?

Tags: java, android, imageview, uri

In my app I need to take a pic from the gallery(I have working code for that, that gives me the Uri of the pic) and place the Uri in an ImageView. The problem I'm running into is that the pic is not covering the whole screen like I want it to, even though I have the height and width of the ImageVIew set to match_parent in the layout. Is there any way I can set every pic from the gallery to display on the whole sceen?

Here's my code:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);              
            img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
        }
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v.getId()==btn.getId())
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
    }
}
```

And here's my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
    android:id="@+id/gallery"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />


                <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pic"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: could you display your code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following `android:scaleType="fitXY"`